# Install Cyanogenmod 7.2 on Nexus One using ClockworkMod Recovery - "remote: signature verify fail"

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, nexus-one, recovery-mode

Steps I've done:

1. Downloaded & copied CM7.2 to my SD card (from [here](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager/device/passion/developer/cyanogenmod?manifest=http://jenkinsmanifest.clockworkmod.com/manifest/release&name=CyanogenMod&deviceName=Google%20Nexus%20One))
2. Installed the Android SDK
3. Downloaded & copied the ClockworkMod Recovery to the platform-tools directory in the SDK folder (from [here](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager))
4. Rebooted my phone by holding down the volume-down and power buttons
5. Went into fastboot mode
6. On my laptop I ran "fastboot oem unlock", then ran it again to make sure it really worked

   [image]
7. On my laptop I ran "fastboot flash recovery recovery-clockwork-5.0.2.0-passion.img"

This is where I get the error "remote: signature verify fail"

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have you disabled signature verification?

Comment: don't know... how do I do that?